# What is this spider

Tags: zoology, species-identification, poison

[image]

What is this spider? Is it poisonous?

Comment: What is the location and climate? What is the approximative size?

Comment: The eyes (and other structure of the head) are key for spider identification. Can you take a picture of the dorsal side of the spider?

Answer (score 3):

This is unambiguously a female *Araneus*, and judging from coloration pattern of the legs and ventrum — very likely the common cross spider *[Araneus diadematus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araneus_diadematus)*: see [ventral view photos](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbm=isch&q=Araneus%20diadematus%20ventral%20view), or some other very similar species. A better photo of the specimen from the dorsal side and some information on the location would be very helpful.

And no, these spiders are not poisonous.

[image: Araneus diadematus]
Photo: Michael Gäbler, via Wikimedia Commons